# Internet access: dsl cable to ethernet in the router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, modem, rj-45

Can I access to internet by using not the RJ11 to RJ11 cable, but a cable RJ11 to RJ45, namely a cable with a dsl tip and an ethernet tip like [this](https://www.amazon.it/RJ11-RJ45-telefono-cavo/dp/B00F4Y60U6/ref=asc_df_B00F4Y60U6/?tag=googshopit-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=392730586973&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17250073760467829359&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=20599&hvtargid=pla-377492226711&psc=1&language=it_IT&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=79187018817&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=392730586973&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17250073760467829359&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=20599&hvtargid=pla-377492226711)?

I didn't find a solution of this type on the web; I want to know this information only for curiosity.

Comment: What's wrong with the cable you found?

Comment: @harrymc I don't know if it's ok for my purpose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean directly connecting the phone line to your Ethernet router, no it won't work. You might even damage your router! DSL has voltages, rates and protocols which are completely incompatible with Ethernet. You need an DSL modem to convert the DSL signal to an Ethernet signal, which you can then feed into your Ethernet router.

Comment: You also need a POTS splitter, otherwise known as an [ADSL splitter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/slp/adsl-splitter/83z634eef3sh3ng) which is used to separate the voice signal from the ADSL signal - as they both come over the same wire from your provider.

Answer (score 0):

The cable you found doesn't specifically mention how it can be used.

However, other cables of the same type are better advertised, but as cable extenders
for ADSL, not for internet.

One example from Amazon is:
[RJ11 to RJ45 Cable 3ft Ethernet Modem Data Telephone ASDL Patch Lead Broadband High Speed Internet Plug 6P4C to 8P8C Flat Network Extension Cord Compatible with Modem, Router, Landline Wire (Black)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XPVJ1TZ).

The description says:

> Modem data cable is designed for connecting ADSL modems or routers to ADSL filtered faceplates, or sending phone lines through dedicated LAN cables

Your would still need a modem/router for translating the ADSL to usable internet
connection.